# syntax error: unexpected end of file trying to run a simple bash script

Tags: bash, cygwin, eof

I really can't see what the issue is with my script is. I've considered missing quotations or other syntax errors. There's got to be something I'm missing. It's a very simple while loop script...

```
#!/bin/bash
c=1
while [ $c -le 5 ]
do
    echo "Welcone $c times"
    c=$(( c++ ))
done
```

I should mention that I'm running bash in cygwin on windows 7.

thanks for the help

Comment: Could it be a strange Windows whitespace character? I tried running it in Linux and [got the following output](http://i.imgur.com/4xBwoPL.png).

Comment: Did you use a windows editor (like Notepad) to create this file?  If so, you've probably got end-of-line problems.  Try using `dos2unix` to convert it (and read the man page, it overwrites its input).

Comment: probably is. I guess I just wont think about it too much and I'll try running it in linux when I can. (I can't install dos2unix in windows with sudo apt-get apparently... if you have a workaround I'd appreciate it ^ ^)

Comment: Use Notepad++ on windows. It has a setting for line endings (and syntax highlighting, etc).

Comment: `tr -d '\r' < your-script.sh > temp.sh; mv temp.sh your-script.sh`

Comment: In addition to the DOS line endings, this won't work: `c=$(( c++ ))`.    Replace that line with simply `(( c++ ))` and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
c=$(( c++ ))
```

to

```
(( c=c+1 ))
```

When Bash sees: (( var)) it will try and 'do some math' on contents... In this case 'c++' == empty string == '0'; c will always be equal to '1' due to 1st assignment...

From the Bash man page on my Linux system (you may need to review this for Cygwin - could be different...):

*((expression))
The expression is evaluated according to the rules described below under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  If the value of the expression is non-zero, the return  status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1.  This is exactly equivalent to let "expression".*

Also:

```
  id++ id--  
          variable post-increment and post-decrement  
  ++id --id  
          variable pre-increment and pre-decrement
```

After a little testing, the 'pre-increment' seems to do what you are after here - note that you may need to declare 'c' as an integer:

```
typeset -i c=1
while [ $c -le 5 ]
do
    echo "Welcone $c times"
    c=++c
#    (( c=c+1 ))
done
```